# After Magento upgrade 1.6 to 1.9 its show error

Tags: magento-1.9

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object
>   in
>   C:\wamp\www\magento-1.9\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\header.phtml
>   on line 33

Comment: please source the header.phtml file and its block class if is custom

Answer (score 2):

This happens if the user for the logged in admin cannot be found but somehow you are still in the admin panel. It's usually a session problem, and deleting your cookies and logging in again should fix it.